# How to find the average time? SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, average

I have a request like this:

[image]

```
created_at  - datetime
```

I need to find the average time for each status. For example, add up the time of all statuses 2 and divide by their number. As a result, get something like 2 days 5 hours.

How to fix my request to make belt operations possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not add image as sample data or desired result.

Comment: If you have a db<>fiddle why don't you post the link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your limited example data, something like this does the job, although it's not pretty:

```
declare @deals table(
    deal_id int,
    status_id int,
    created_at datetime
)

insert into @deals values
(1,1,'2021-05-12 18:54:00.000'),
(1,2,'2021-05-13 13:34:00.000'),
(1,3,'2021-05-17 14:39:00.000'),
(1,2,'2021-05-18 09:24:00.000'),
(1,3,'2021-05-18 09:24:00.000'),
(1,4,'2021-05-18 10:27:00.000'),
(1,5,'2021-05-19 13:00:00.000'),
(1,4,'2021-05-19 13:00:00.000'),
(1,5,'2021-05-24 08:06:00.000'),
(2,1,'2021-05-14 17:31:00.000')

select 
    status_id,
    cast(avg(datediff(minute,cast(created_at as date),created_at))/60 as varchar(2)) + ':' + right('0' + cast(avg(datediff(minute,cast(created_at as date),created_at)) - ((avg(datediff(minute,cast(created_at as date),created_at))/60)*60) as varchar(2)),2) as averageTime
from @deals
group by status_id
order by status_id
```

You get these results:

[image: Results]

Comment: This is genius!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If not difficult, could you explain what these expressions mean?
  + ':' + 
right('0' + cast  whay '0'?

Comment: and fore what varchar(2)) ?

Comment: I'm adding the leading zero so that if the value is a single digit, it presents correctly in the result. I cast to `varchar(2)` as that's the max length of the numeric value as a string once it's converted.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please consider accepting it. 